# How to encode Hasse diagram with 0's and 1's

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

Boolean algebra is defined as lattice which is isomorphic with $B_n$. I know how to construct Hasse diagram. But couldnt understand how to assign 0's and 1's to nodes. [image].

Please tell the general mechanism for assigning boolean values to hasse diagram.

> $B_n$ is defined as : If the Hasse diagram of the lattice
>   corresponding to a set with $n$ elements is labeled by sequences of 0
>   and 1 of length $n$, then the resulting lattice is named $B_n$

Comment: Your definition of a Boolean algebra is unclear. What is $B_n$?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Question edited to include $B_n$. I am looking for the way to give the nodes a number that is made up of sequence of 0 and 1. For example, for a 8 node hasse diagram three bits starting with 000 and ending with 111 can be used. I know that the greatest element is 111 and least element is 000. I want to know how the nodes are numbered for intermediate nodes. I have read that pidgin-coding can be used. But couldn't understand more

Answer (score 1):

In your diagram nodes can be seen at various levels. Level $k$ means exactly $k$ 1's are present in the length $n$ string.

A  slanted line joining two nodes  means a single zero in the node below has been changed to 1.

For example in the last diagram
by starting with $000000$ for the bottom most element one scans the row above left to right and replace that 0 into 1.
So level 1   it will be $10000, 01000,00100,00010,00001$. Continue in the same way until you reach the top which is a node with all 1's.  Thats all.